# calculus 2 - surfaces and Implicit function question (homework)

Tags: calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I am stuck hard on this one:
find all constants C so that the surfaces:
$$X^2+Y^2+Z^2=1$$
$$Z=X^2+Y^2+C
$$
1)Tangent at the common points

2)perpendicular at the common points.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $f(x,y,z) = x^2 +y^2 +z^2 -1$ and $g(x,y,z) = z -x^2 -y^2 -c$. Then you have your pair of surfaces for $f(x,y,z) = 0$ and $g(x,y,z) =0$.

Steps for part 1:

1. If they are tangent at common points then their normal vectors are collinear. Using gradients you have $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$. Use this to find a condition for $\lambda$.
2. This will give you $z$. Solve the system $$\begin{cases} x^2+y^2+z^2 & = 1, \\ z -x^2-y^2 & = c, \end{cases}$$ to find the value of $c$.

Steps for part 2:

1. If they are orthogonal at common points then their normal vectors are orthogonal. Using gradients you have $\nabla f \cdot \nabla g = 0$. Use this to find an equation relating $z, x$ and $y$.
2. Use the same system to find the value of $c$.

Comment: Let me just make sure that I understand what you mean clearly. The demand for the 2 surfaces to be tanget/orthogonal at coomon points allows me to use the ideas of the gradient that youve mentioned. In this way i can find the z value of the points who stand for that demand, and from there i can use that z point for both of the equations because i know that both of them needs to fulfill the common points?

Comment: Or you can first solve the quadratic $Z^2+Z-C-1=0$ to find the circles of intersection and compare then the tangent planes.

Comment: @user3921 Yes, that is correct. LutzL's suggestion is also nice.